# Js regEx parsing woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing

So I am having some trouble parsing a string. I need to parse out "images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId"
from

```
"url(http://some/folder/path/images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId)"
```

I have tried using regEx but I am not sufficiently knowledgable of them for such a large and specific substring. Any help would help, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you have given enough information to solve your problem. What are the different possible paths? What pieces of that path will be consistent?

Comment: `"url(http://some/folder/path/images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId)".match(/\/images\/.*/);`

Comment: Hey caspian, the string that is in the code block is what needs to be parsed, and the images string above it is the bit that I need. So I am not sure what your comment means by mentioning possible paths or consistency.

Comment: Karl, that match function was buggy when I ran it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this **specific** string, you can use the following if you insist on using regular expression:

```
var s = 'url(http://some/folder/path/images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId)';
    s = s.replace(/.*(?=images)|\W$/g, '');

console.log(s); //=> 'images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId'
```

Or using the String [`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method..

```
var s = 'url(http://some/folder/path/images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId)',
    r = s.match(/images[^)]*/);

console.log(r[0]); //=> 'images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId'
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I am seeing is that you have some base url, `http://some/folder/path/`, wrapped around a CSS `url()`. Have a go at the following:

```
var base_url    = 'http://some/folder/path/';
var search      = 'url(http://some/folder/path/images/foo/bar/anotherfoo/imageId)';

// That replace is adding back slashes to the base_url so that the regex expression 
// doesn't get confused. You could also just remove it entirely, but since you wanted
// a regex based expression...
var pattern     = '/url(' + base_url.replace(/\//g, '\\/') + '([\w\/]+)\))/i';

if(regex.test(input))
{
    var matches = input.match(regex);
    for(var match in matches)
    {
        alert(matches[match]);
    } 
}
else
{
    alert("No matches found!");
}
```

If you want to learn more about Regular Expression, I recommend you go over to [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/) for tutorials and exercises - learn best by doing.

Comment: this is a good, but I am giving the answer to hwnd for a more succinct solution to my problem. And yes, I am trying to parse out a filepath from a css url().